# IIS and ARR least response time algorithm sample duration

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8, arr

When choosing the load balance algorithm Least Response Time we can set a sample duration (seconds). I could not find a description of the functional use of this parameter with the least response time algorithm. What does this parameter do? We have different pages which respond in different times, how do we take this in account when selecting a webserver to direct traffic to?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm uses your `Health Test` page and sends the traffic to the content server with fastest load/response time. All servers would be serving the same page/content, but due to load or other variables one may be faster than the others.

From [ARR - Load Balance Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd443524(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Least response time – Distributes traffic based on the fastest
>   response time from the servers, which enables the server to respond
>   most quickly.

[Tutorial here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing)

Comment: I am looking for a description of what the parameter sample duration (seconds) does which is not clear when reading IIS documentation.